# How to position a tag with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-api

I am using the Google search API (https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/) and I am wondering how to position the search results horizontal instead of vertical. (I am only using the Image searcher)

The results for images are displayed in a class called `.gs-image-box` so I tried referencing the results by their tag name which is `img`:

```
function floatRight() {
    var searchresults=getElementsByClassName("gs-image-box");
    var badgeimg = searchresults[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
    badgeimg.style.cssFloat = "right";
}
```

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think that all you need to do to get your floatRight() function to work is use `document.getElementsbyClassName()`.

Comment: What is `cssFloat` supposed to be?

Comment: I thought cssFLoat is the term for JS to float elements

Comment: Should be `badgeimg.style.float = "right"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick

```
.gs-result{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sorry! forgot that, gs-result is a tag above the gs-image-box. The inline-block references  all the tags below http://jsfiddle.net/o9s0h7j0/